# How client sends close signal to graphql subscription server?

Tags: go, websocket, graphql, subscription, gqlgen

I'm working on a graphql server and there is one subscription API. This is the starter code I found on gqlgen documentation:

```
// CurrentTime is the resolver for the currentTime field.
func (r *subscriptionResolver) CurrentTime(ctx context.Context) (<-chan *model.Time, error) {
    // First you'll need to `make()` your channel. Use your type here!
    ch := make(chan *model.Time)

    // You can (and probably should) handle your channels in a central place outside of `schema.resolvers.go`.
    // For this example we'll simply use a Goroutine with a simple loop.
    go func() {
        // Handle deregistration of the channel here. Note the `defer`
    defer close(ch)

        for {
            // In our example we'll send the current time every second.
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            fmt.Println("Tick")

            // Prepare your object.
            currentTime := time.Now()
            t := &model.Time{
                UnixTime:  int(currentTime.Unix()),
                TimeStamp: currentTime.Format(time.RFC3339),
            }

            // The subscription may have got closed due to the client disconnecting.
            // Hence we do send in a select block with a check for context cancellation.
            // This avoids goroutine getting blocked forever or panicking,
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done(): // This runs when context gets cancelled. Subscription closes.
                fmt.Println("Subscription Closed")
                // Handle deregistration of the channel here. `close(ch)`
                return // Remember to return to end the routine.
            
            case ch <- t: // This is the actual send.
                // Our message went through, do nothing 
            }
        }
    }()

    // We return the channel and no error.
    return ch, nil
}
```

I want to know what happens when I receive ctx.Done() signal. Is the client sending this signal by unsubscribing or closing subscription? Or it can happen automatically after some time?( I mean setting some timeout parameter for being idle.)
Also, I want to know can a timeout on my side(server side) trigers Done() signal?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the weksocket implemetation of gqlgen (the [run](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/blob/296b3c49071be2dbb5303b46f3f4a4861e19a5a8/graphql/handler/transport/websocket.go#L236) implementation in particular), we can see that a `context.WithCancel` is created, and the `cancel` function is called in the `defer` function.
So the context is canceled whenever we exit the `run` function (e.g. when the client close the connection sending a `connectionCloseMessageType` or a unexpected message like in the default case).

That `cancel` triggers the `ctx.Done()` that closes the subscription, since the context is the same.

You can add your own timeout or deadline directly into the resolver using the `context.WithDeadline` or `context.WithTimeout` if you want to close the connection after a certain amount of time.

You can also use the [`InitFunc`](https://gqlgen.com/recipes/authentication/#websockets) to provide a common logic among all you subscribe resolver, like we can see in this [proposal](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/issues/1727):

```
server.AddTransport(&transport.Websocket{
    Upgrader: websocket.Upgrader{
        CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
            return true
        },
    },
    KeepAlivePingInterval: 10 * time.Second,
    InitFunc: func(ctx context.Context, initPayload transport.InitPayload) (context.Context, *transport.InitPayload, error) {
                    payloadAuth := initPayload.Authorization()
        if payloadAuth == "" {
            return ctx, &initPayload, errors.New("the JWT is missing in the initialization payload")
        }

        jwt, err := authenticateJWT(payloadAuth)
        if err != nil {
            return ctx,&initPayload, err
        }

        // Add the JWT expiration as a deadline, and add the reason
        newCtx, _ := context.WithDeadline(transport.AppendCloseReason(ctx, "authentication token has expired"), time.Unix(jwt.ExpiresAt, 0))
        return newCtx, &initPayload,nil
    },
})
```